# Manifest for java:8-jre-alpine not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown

Tags: java, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, build

I'm facing this error while building on Ubuntu server:

> Step 1/10 : FROM java:8-jre-alpine
>
> ERROR: Service 'XXXX' failed to build: manifest for java:8-jre-alpine not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown

It was working fine since months, suddenly now its not working. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I change java:8 to openjdk:8 and it works.

Answer (score 6):

The issue could appear due to deprecation of java image:

[image]

amazoncorretto:8-alpine or openjdk:8-alpine will be a good replacement.

Answer (score 1):

I change java:8 to amazoncorretto:8 and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

openjdk:8 or amazoncorretto:8 work for me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the manifest file does not likely exist; the version/tag you have chosen does not exist. Since docker images are built from the manifest file of the image:tag, if the manifest file does not exist for the image/tag, the docker image will not be built, thus the error.

**Fix:** Select an image with a valid tag.